# Mongoose Version Error and no matching document found for id

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema, and I just added the field "imagens" in the original schema.

The field added is:

```
imagens:[{title:{type: String},savedAs:{type: String},file:{type: String}, thumb:{type: String}}],
```

Now when I try fill the 'imagens' field and update the collection, I get the next error.
And if I get rid off the line 'item.imagens=imgs' the error is gone.

What am I doing wrong? Is there some fix to this problem?

//Error

```
     {"data":{"message":"No matching document found for id \"5909caeed32a453b537f7966\"",
"name":"VersionError"},    "status":500,
        "config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback",
    "url":"/uploads",
    "data":{"file":{"$ngfBlobUrl":
    "blob:http://localhost/9c4b0449-1ddd-4e39-ab44-f2e9a21bfd82","$ngfWidth":450,"$ngfHeight":321,
    "upload":{},"progress":100},"pacID":"5909caeed32a453b537f7966"},"_isDigested":true,
    "_chunkSize":null,"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"},"_deferred":{"promise":"..."},"cached":false},"statusText":"Internal Server Error"}
```

//in my router

```
Cliente.findById(pac_id, function (err, item) {  
                                    if (err) {
                                        return res.status(500).send(err);
                                    } else {
                                       item.imagens=imgs
                                    }
                                    item.save(function (err, data) {
                                      if (err) {
                                            return res.status(500).send(err)
                                      }
                                      if (answers.results.length){
                                            answers.message='Some files was not uploaded'
                                      } else {
                                            answers.message='Files were uploaded'
                                      }
                                      res.send(answers)  
                                   })
                                  })
```

//model

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const clientesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: {type: Number, unique:true},
  nome: {type: String, unique:true},
  ativo: {type: Boolean},
  ...
  ...  
  foto: { data: Buffer, contentType: String },
  imagens:[{title:{type: String},savedAs:{type: String},file:{type: String}, thumb:{type: String}}],
  created_at:{type:Date,default:Date.now},
  altered_at:{type:Date,default:Date.now}
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Cliente', clientesSchema,'clientes' );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose VersionError: No matching document found for id when document is being saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54792749/mongoose-versionerror-no-matching-document-found-for-id-when-document-is-being)

Comment: Possible duplicate with explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54792749/mongoose-versionerror-no-matching-document-found-for-id-when-document-is-being

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delete the document version, that will resolve the version conflict.
Then Mongoose will allow you to save :

```
delete item.__v
item.save(...)
```

Comment: Thank you Jeremy, but  I tried it and the problem continues. It´s weird, because If I put only one  image into my "imagens" array, the problem doesn´t appears. If I put two or more image items into field array, I have the problem showing

Comment: Thank you, it was it. I made a mistake.

Comment: Are there any dangerous-unforeseen consequences to this? Is it fine to leave this in the code permanently?