# Mongoose VersionError: No matching document found for id when document is being saved

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am repeatedly seeing the following error when synchronizing a users cart through a "/sync/" API request. This is called whenever a user changes the contents of their shopping cart.

> VersionError: No matching document found for id
>   "2y4b1hq601cd013e0af25e32" version 4 modifiedPaths "cart, cart.items,
>   cart.updatedAt"
>       at VersionError.MongooseError [as constructor] (/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/mongooseError.js:13:11)
>       at new VersionError (/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/version.js:18:17)
>       at generateVersionError (/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:398:10)
>       at model.Model.save (/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:460:27)
>       at /controllers/shoppingCart/index.js:48:14
>       at /node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4670:16
>       at /node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:258:16
>       at _hooks.execPost (/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4065:11)
>       at /node_modules/kareem/index.js:135:16
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)

The exact code line is the following:

```
req.session.save();
delete user.__v;
>>      user.save();
return res.send();
```

I've tried user.increment() but this doesn't seem to fix this, nor deleting user.__v I am assuming this is conflicting versions, and I want versioning on my user objects, I just need to force the cart to always sync to the latest version.

Answer (score 20):

While it would appear a **.save()** is the right approach here, an **.update()** command would get the job done while ignoring "race conditions" that cause this error to occur. Mongo DB is throwing this error because it is concerned that I am saving an older version of the document that has already been updated:

1. v1 is sent to client
2. v1 is saved, and updated to v2 in Mongo DB
3. v1 is trying to be saved again, but Mongo DB already has v2 stored, error is thrown

A better approach is to send v1 to the client and when the cart object changes, synchronize the object with the new cart object no matter what. This can be done via **.update()** rather than through **.save()**.

This is because **.save()** watches and cares about version controls, while **.update()** will update the object regardless of version control.

Comment: ty million times :D

Comment: I'm trying this as I have the same error but for some reasson the collection remains empty. I want to clarify that I'm trying to make a copy of some of the documents of the original collection to a new db; at the begining I used model.save() and it started throwing the version error and changed it to model.updateOne() but now the new collection is created on the new db but it remainds empty. Do you know what may be causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

It was failing for me because `_id` field of a document that I fetched and tried to update was stored in the db as a string, not ObjectId.
Check what is that particular `user._id` datatype.

If it is string - you'll need to insert new document and remove that existing one to fix it, since `_id` field is immutable.